# Destination:= moving just values?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following piece of code to move data if anything has been marked as yes, however, using this any data validation etc is moved across as well. Is there away I can get the following to work and only place the value of the cell, leaving the original data validation etc in place on the new sheet? I have tried both .value and using .PasteSpecial and I'm currently stuck.

```
  If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("G8:G101"), "Yes") >= 1 Then

    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="Yes"
    Range("B8:F101").Copy Destination:=Sheet4.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    Range("H8:L101").Copy Destination:=Sheet4.Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    Range("B8:K101").ClearContents
    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=6
```

Answer (score 0):

Please post your original code as PasteSpecial does work.

Anyway:

```
'PasteSpecial method
'note: destination cells outside the original count will be unchanged
Range("B8:F101").Copy
Sheet4.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'direct assignment method
'note: destination cells outside the original count will be overwritten with #N/A
Sheet4.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = Range("B8:F101").Value
```